# Azure pipeline Release pipeline: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope fails with ,,Error code: DeploymentFailed"

Tags: azure, debugging, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

The ARM template seems fine, no validation errors occur, and variables seem to be defined, not sure how should I debug this weird error message.

````
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4710207Z ==============================================================================
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4710434Z Task         : ARM template deployment
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4710576Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template to all the deployment scopes
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4710814Z Version      : 3.210.1
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4710932Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4711075Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment
2023-01-25T16:46:49.4711307Z ==============================================================================
2023-01-25T16:46:49.6711981Z ARM Service Connection deployment scope - Subscription
2023-01-25T16:46:49.6897349Z Checking if the following resource group exists: APP-RG-DEV-NE.
2023-01-25T16:46:49.9703739Z Resource group exists: true.
2023-01-25T16:46:49.9707493Z Creating deployment parameters.
2023-01-25T16:46:50.7941256Z Starting template validation.
2023-01-25T16:46:50.8120966Z Deployment name is azuredeploy-20230125-164650-9976
2023-01-25T16:46:55.8082119Z Template deployment validation was completed successfully.
2023-01-25T16:46:55.8082485Z Starting Deployment.
2023-01-25T16:46:55.8083063Z Deployment name is azuredeploy-20230125-164650-9976
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5609488Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5641699Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5651004Z ##[error]Details:
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5651895Z ##[error]BadRequest: 
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5652688Z ##[error]BadRequest: 
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5653453Z ##[error]BadRequest: 
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5654221Z ##[error]BadRequest: 
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5654988Z ##[error]BadRequest: 
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5656695Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5658246Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
2023-01-25T16:48:05.5682468Z ##[section]Finishing: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope
```
````

Comment: If you go to the Resource Group you are deploying to and look at the Deployments tab that deployment should show.  See if there is more detail there.

Comment: Same Error.......    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": ""
    } }

How people are developing with Azure seems so crazy it won't tell you what is happening and what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the issue, which was pretty stupid not sure why the error message was not clearer about name violations.

The secret name for the key vault contained a dot (.) in it and was failing because of it.